# TYPO3: How to render localized tt_content in own extension

Tags: typo3

One way to render a tt_content element from own extension is this:

```
function getCE($id)
{
    $conf['tables'] = 'tt_content';
    $conf['source'] = $id;
    $conf['dontCheckPid'] = 1;
    return $this->cObj->cObjGetSingle('RECORDS', $conf);
}
```

Is it possible to add something to $conf so tt_content is rendered localized? Lets say I want the tt_content row with sys_language_uid = 2.

Alternative is to use the "getRecordOverlay", but then some functionality from cObjGetSingle will be lost.

**UPDATE** (it is for TYPO3 4.5.10)

Thank you for feedback. I somehow do it wrong with the 'CONTENT' way of doing it. I get nothing back from the function. Neither with or without the languageField.

Is it possible to post a working example? Lets say I know the tt_content uid is 3389 and it has been translated to language with uid 2. Or a link to a simple working example.

```
$conf = array(
    'table'   => 'tt_content',
    'select.' => array(
        'where'         => 'colPos=0 AND uid = 3389',
        'orderBy'       => 'sorting',
        'languageField' => 2 << if I leave this line out of the conf array I still get no result
    )
);
return $this->cObj->cObjGetSingle('CONTENT', $conf);
```

BR. Anders

Answer (score 1):

You might try using [CONTENT](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html) instead of RECORDS:

```
$conf = array(
    'table'   => 'tt_content',
    'select.' => array(
        'where'         => 'colPos=0',
        'orderBy'       => 'sorting',
        'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid' // <- Here!
    )
);
$conf['select.']['languageField'] = 'sys_language_uid';

return $this->cObj->cObjGetSingle('CONTENT', $conf);
```

Comment: Thanks you for your example. I cannot make it work. I have updated my question. If you have time, please post a simple working example

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `RECORDS` with `CONTENT` and adjust the `$conf` array accordingly.
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html

`CONTENT` makes use of `select` http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Select/Index.html and that again can use `languageField` for the proper selection of translated content.

But you will have to connect it to the original `$id`, since content elements do "know" their original element by the `l18n_parent` field. You can use `where` or `andWhere` for it.

Comment: with the code example posted by helmbert you won't get a specific content element but the whole content of column "normal" with the currently selected language.

You should set the l18n_parent to $id within the where clause, to make sure you will get the translation for that particular element only.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I cannot make it work even though I have tried to read and understand the links you posted. I have updated my question. If you have time, please post a simple working example.