# TYPO3: How to render translated content in extension

Tags: typo3

I am developing a TYPO3 6.0 plugin that shows the subpages of the current page as tabs. For example, on the following pages my plugin is inserted on `TabRoot`:

[image: Example TYPO3 pages]

If `TabRoot` is requested, the plugin's `ActionController` looks up the database for the subpage titles and contents and passes all gathered data to a Fluid template. The page is then rendered like the following:

[image: Tab selector functionality]

With JS in place I always hide/show content below based on the selection. My problem is that I want to show the ***translated content*** of the subpages based on the current language selection. How am I able to do this? I've tried it with several methods, but neither of them was flawless. These are the methods I've tried:

---

**Using [`RECORDS`](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Records/Index.html)** This method is not affected by the selected language, it always returns the content in the default language:

```php
//Get the ids of the parts of the page

$select_fields = "uid";
$from_table = "tt_content";
$where_clause = 'pid = ' . $pageId;
$res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery(
      $select_fields,
      $from_table,
      $where_clause,
      $groupBy='',
      $orderBy='sorting',
      $limit=''
);

$ids = '';
$firstIteration = true;
while ( $row = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc( $res ) ) {
    if (!$firstIteration) $ids .= ",";
    $ids .= $row ['uid'];

    $firstIteration = false;
}
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_free_result( $res );

//Render the parts of the page

$conf ['tables'] = 'tt_content';
$conf ['source'] = $ids;
$conf ['dontCheckPid'] = 1;
$content = $this->cObj->cObjGetSingle ( 'RECORDS', $conf );
```

---

**Using [`CONTENTS`](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html)** According to [TYPO3: How to render localized tt_content in own extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16597561/157762), this is the way to do it, however for me this also returns the content rendered with the default language. It is not affected by a language change.

```php
$conf = array(
    'table' => 'tt_content',
    'select.' => array(
            'pidInList' => $pageId,
            'orderBy'  => 'sorting',
            'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid'
    )
);
$content = $this->cObj->cObjGetSingle ( 'CONTENT', $conf );
```

---

**Using VHS: Fluid ViewHelpers** I installed the [`vhs`](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/vhs) extension and tried to render the content with [`<v:content.render />`](http://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Content/RenderViewHelper.html). The result is the same as with `CONTENTS`; it only works with the default language.

```xml
{namespace v=Tx_Vhs_ViewHelpers}

...

<v:content.render column="0" order="'sorting'" sortDirection="'ASC'"
        pageUid="{pageId}" render="1" hideUntranslated="1" />
```

---

**Using my own SQL query** I've tried to get the `bodytext` fields of the page and then render those with [`\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Plugin\AbstractPlugin::pi_RTEcssText()`](http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_frontend_1_1_plugin_1_1_abstract_plugin.html#a96c80fb7a5c1a3939d53019651e4890f). This method returns the content based on the current language, however the problem is that `bodytext`'s do not contain the complete content (images, other plugins, etc).

```php
$select_fields = "bodytext";
$from_table = "tt_content";
$where_clause = 'pid = ' . $pageId
    . ' AND sys_language_uid = ' . $GLOBALS ['TSFE']->sys_language_uid;
$res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery(
      $select_fields,
      $from_table,
      $where_clause,
      $groupBy='',
      $orderBy='sorting',
      $limit=''
);

$content = '';
while ( $row = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc( $res ) ) {
   $content .= 
   \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Plugin\AbstractPlugin::pi_RTEcssText( $row ['bodytext'] );
}
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_free_result( $res );
```

---

What am I missing? Why isn't the content rendered with the current language in the case of the `CONTENTS` method?

Comment: Just an idea: If you are using fluid, maybe using the vhs extension, specifically one of the *Menu-ViewHelpers could do the trick? http://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Page/Menu/DirectoryViewHelper.html

Comment: @Jost I managed to render the page content with the default language, but I couldn't get this to work with a different language.

Comment: Why using an extension? You can do this with pure TS. I suggest to reduce the extension to a cObject viewhelper and doing the logic in `TypoScript.` http://t3brightside.com/blog/article/typoscript-page-teaser-display-list-of-sub-pages-with-images/

Comment: @pgampe Thanks! I did not try it yet, but I accepted your answer since you have been helping me a lot already. Building an extension feels natural to me, since then I just have to add it to the desired pages on the backend. Also, the `CONTENTS` method is based on TS, so I would expect it to work. But then again, I am new to TYPO3 and I understand PHP way better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to use the cObject viewhelper to render right from `TypoScript`.

And inside your `TypoScript` template provide the configuration:

```
lib.myContent = CONTENT
lib.myContent {
  ...
}
```

BTW, you are bypassing the TYPO3 CMS API. Please do not do so. Always use the API methods to query for data.
e.g. `\TYPO3\CMS\core\Database\DatabaseConnection` is always available at `GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->`. Do not use the the `mysql` function.

On top of that, I believe that you can archive whatever you are trying to do with pure `TypoScript`, without the need to program anything. Feel free to ask a new questions to get help on this.

Comment: Thanks for your response! You are right, I just figured out that I have to use `GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']`. But still, I am clueless why the `CONTENTS` method is not working. For example if I set `"where" => "sys_language_uid = 1"`, nothing is returned, however it works with the default language.

I only have an `ActionController` that prepares data for a Fluid template. How does TypoScript fit in my extension? This is why I would prefer to retrieve the translated content in PHP.

Comment: You need to either do the language overlay on your own, but then you do not need the content object, or you rely on ``TypoScript`` , but then you need to configure it correctly. Please state why you are trying to render the page content inside the a controller. What is your goal? Please clarify your question. Then we might be able to suggest a working method.

Comment: I have updated the first part of my question which describes the desired functionality. Let me know if something is still unclear!

Answer (score 0):

In TYPO3 4.x you could use the following methods to load the translated record:

- `t3lib_pageSelect->getRecordOverlay`
- `t3lib_pageSelect->getPageOverlay`

They are also available at `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_page->getRecordOverlay()`.